# How can I add tooltips to tabs in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, tooltip

I have been struggling to add tooltips to tabs in react. I have been able to add them to buttons just fine with the following snippet using Tooltip from react-bootstrap but when I wrap a tab element with OverlayTrigger from react-bootstrap it causes the tab to disappear:

```
  <OverlayTrigger placement="bottom" overlay={<Tooltip id="tooltip">TooltipTest</Tooltip>}>
   <Button bsStyle="default">Test Button</Button>
  </OverlayTrigger>
```

I have attempted to use the Tooltip from react-bootstrap, ReactToolTip fron react-tooltip and Tooltip from reactstrap but all either cause the tab to disappear or only cause the text within the tab to trigger the tooltip.

Here is my render function:

```
render() {

    return (
      <Tabs activeKey={this.state.key} onSelect={this.handleSelect} id="controlled-tab-example">
        <Tab eventKey={1} title="Summary">Summary View</Tab>
        <Tab eventKey={2} title="All Trades">All Trades Report</Tab>
        <Tab eventKey={3} title="Reports">Reports</Tab>
        <Tab eventKey={4} title="Completeness - ABC Only">Completeness - ABC Only</Tab>
        <Tab eventKey={5} title="Completeness - DEF Only">Completeness - DEF Only</Tab>
        <Tab eventKey={6} title="Completeness - Matches">Completeness - Matches</Tab>
        <Tab eventKey={7} title="Unmatched">Unmatched</Tab>
        <Tab eventKey={8} title="Rejects">Rejects</Tab>
        <Tab eventKey={9} title="Amendments">Amendments</Tab>
        <Tab eventKey={10} title="Late Trades">Late Trades</Tab>
      </Tabs>
    );
  }
```

Comment: This Question is Answered Here and worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60770136/how-to-place-a-tooltip-for-the-react-bootstrap-tab-component